# Is there any form designer available for Google Android

Tags: java, android

I am a new comer in Android development, I have downloaded and installed the Android SDK, but not find any GUI or Form designer, can any one know about some Form designer in for Android, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As d. correctly mentioned the built-in designer does not truly represent your view.
And if we keep in mind that even after 4 years of trying, Microsoft's equivalent for their XAML code still doesn't reach minimum usefulness level, I would strongly recommend to go manual. It's faster, much more difficult but equally rewarding. Once you get a hang of editing the XML files manually the development becomes much easier and WAY faster in my humble opinion.
Regards

Answer (score 19):

The form designer is part of the [Android Development Tools (ADT) Plugin for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) which comes with the Android SDK.

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but the form designer is terrible, and it mutilates your code even worse than the visual studio design view

Comment: There is no form designer related info in the given link.

Comment: Create a new Android project in Eclipse, double-click on res/layout/main.xml and you will see the GUI editor. New XML files created in that directory should also open with the GUI editor.

Comment: Does Netbeans IDE have any analog?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is very late to the game but each new release of the Eclipse Android plugin improves the layout GUI editor. The one released yesterday (9.0.0) is light years ahead of the original tools which were awful.

Answer (score 1):

Google has not announced any plans for a wysiwyg designer for Android app development. However, there is a tool available for this. Check out this link http://www.designerandroid.com/?p=165

Comment: I don't see how that's helpful as in the post you linked to it makes it clear the App Inventor for Android "is only available to participating university students."