# WYSIWYG View Editor in 'Android'?

Tags: xml, android, eclipse, editor, wysiwyg

> **Duplicate**: [Is there any form designer available for Google Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755860/)

I would like to move a CheckBox, so it displays in a different location than the top-left corner under Absolute Layout inside main.xml, for 'Android'.  I'm using Eclipse to edit my views.  How would I do this?

On an iPhone they have a tool called Interface builder that allows you to move things in a WYIWYG fashion.
Does Eclipse have similar functionality?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755860/

Comment: Also, please don't use `AbsoluteLayout`, as that class has been deprecated.

Comment: You could use DroidDraw as an interface builder although it is a bit limited - google it

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a RelativeLayout. You can position your checkbox in relation to other views or the parent view, for example if you want to position it on the right hand side and below a TextView, you could use something like

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    />
  <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also have a look at droiddraw.org but I recommend writing the code yourself as it speeds up the process if you ever need to edit/re-use.

For more info on RelativeLayout look at http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

The Android plugin in Eclipse has a WYSIWYG editor, just open on the layout xml file. However I'm guessing you already know this and want instead to know how to do absolute positioning in a visual editor. The short answer is "no", because Android screens come in lots of different shapes and sizes, unlike (for now) the iPhone.